# Exchange Online PowerShell error - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, identity-management

We are a using an IAM tool that creates user accounts in Active Directory and then run a PowerShell script to enable their remote mailbox in exchange online.

Here is how the script looks like :

```
$so = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck

$ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential $cred -ConnectionUri $msoExchangeURL -Authentication kerberos -SessionOption $so -Verbose

Import-PSSession $ExchangeSession -AllowClobber

Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $UPN

Remove-PSSession $ExchangeSession
```

The tool invokes the PowerShell script separately for each user that gets created on a day and these gets triggered parallelly, which means that multiple PowerShell sessions/exchange sessions gets opened parallelly. The script works perfectly fine when the user count is less, but when the count is large, say 50+, the PowerShell script starts throwing the below error for some of the users :

```
*Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again*
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue while dealing with multiple parallel exchange PowerShell sessions.? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest checking the login logs for the user that runs this script next time it fails, it might be hitting a concurrent logins limit or similar

Comment: We did and even increased the concurrent session limit to 250 but still seeing errors. Just wondering if the Remove-PSSession is not actually closing out the session.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect like this anymore since a while, legacy authentication is not supported.

You must download the latest **ExchangeOnlineManagement** module and use `Connect-ExchangeOnline` command.

Comment: There is no issue with connection. The above said issue occurs only when there are a large number of parallel sessions